# asp mvc best way to return a json string from a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have a simple Action that iterates around a dbset does a bit of manipulation on each record then returns the chosen records via json, a bit like this:

```
List<JsonResult> dataout = new List<JsonResult>();
foreach(var r in db.People.OrderBy("something")) {
    // do stuff to the rec
    string SubmittersName = rec.Submitter.Name;
    dataout.Add(this.Json(new { rec.Created, rec.Name, SubmittersName,  
                     OtherStuff }));
}

return new JsonResult() {
    Data = dataout.Select(r=>r),
    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

To me it seems a bit clumsy, but its easy to follow whats going on.

(Also in the returned json I get ContentEncoding:null which seems a bit strange given that I specified it)

How could this be improved on?

General sugesstions/comments appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing `JsonResult`.

`JsonResult` isn't a way to store JSON data; it's simply a way to return JSON data from a view.
You shouldn't create a list of them.

By returning JSON from a collection of `JsonResult`s, you're actually converting the `JsonResult`s to JSON, including their `ContentEncoding` properties (which you never set).

Instead, you can directly return a collection of anonymous types:

```
return Json(
    db.People.OrderBy(something).Select(rec => new { rec.Created, ... }),
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
);
```

Comment: You can put that in the `Select` call, or add them to a `List<object>`.  (Since you cannot easily declare a list of anonymous types)

Comment: exactly the problem not easliy anyway. ArrayList works which is the way i think i'll go to get rid of the problem. I have tried to put the tranform function into the select but it proved difficult, I kept getting lots of compiler errors about not be able to parse the anon function into an expression tree.

Comment: Oh; you're using LINQ to SQL.  You can fix those errors by calling `AsEnumerable()` before `Select()`.